# Column 'tbl_Stock.Item_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, count, sum

I have a database table named as tbl_stock.

eg:

```
Order_ID  Item_Name  Item_Stock  Item_Dispatched  Item_Avaliable 
........  .......... ..........  ...............  ..............
1           abc           10            2               8
2           abc           13            7               6
3           abc           23            10              13
4           xyz           43            12              31
5           xyz            4            1               3
```

I want to get an out put in gridview as shown below:

```
Item_Name  Item_Stock  Item_Dispatched  Item_Avaliable 
.........  ..........  ...............  ..............
abc           46            19              27
xyz           47            13              33
```

I want to calculate specific column values. While using the given below SQL query showing one error. The error is "`Column 'tbl_Stock.Item_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`"

SQL :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Item_Name, 
COUNT(Item_Stock) AS Item_Stock, 
COUNT(Item_Dispatched) AS Item_Dispatched, 
COUNT(Item_Avaliable) AS Item_Avaliable 
FROM tbl_Stock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the error says, add GROUP BY to calculate totals for each item

```
SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ Item_Name, 
SUM(Item_Stock) AS Item_Stock, 
SUM(Item_Dispatched) AS Item_Dispatched, 
SUM(Item_Avaliable) AS Item_Avaliable 
FROM tbl_Stock
GROUP BY Item_Name
```

also there will be no need in DISTINCT.

`COUNT()` function will return number or rows (3 for abc item in Item_Stock, Item_Dispatched and Item_Avaliable columns and 2 for xyz), so to get desired result change it and use `SUM()`

Answer (score 2):

Add group by clause rather than distinct like:

```
SELECT Item_Name, 
SUM(Item_Stock) AS Item_Stock, 
SUM(Item_Dispatched) AS Item_Dispatched, 
SUM(Item_Avaliable) AS Item_Avaliable 
FROM tbl_Stock
GROUP BY Item_Name
```

It will group all your records by Item_Name and will do SUM on each and every column.

Comment: I was in the process of modifying it and I did modified it.